# SQL Query to get all the count of customers per combination of products

Tags: sql, postgresql

The dataset contains two columns customer and product as below:

[image]

The output required is :

[image]

How many customers have a particular combination of a product?

For example:
customer2 and customer3 both have a combination of Product A and B

I don't have any idea, hence cannot share any code.

Comment: self join, group by, count distinct,

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? And what is the version...

Comment: Its postgresSQL, but either one would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for postgreSQL:

```
with data AS
(
    SELECT * FROM 
        (
            VALUES 
            ('customer1', 'A'),
            ('customer1', 'B'),
            ('customer2', 'C'),
            ('customer2', 'B'),
            ('customer3', 'A'),
            ('customer3', 'B'),
            ('customer3', 'C'),
            ('customer4', 'A'),
            ('customer4', 'C') 
        ) v (customer, product)
),
cte AS
(SELECT DISTINCT d1.product p1, d2.product p2
FROM data d1
INNER JOIN data d2 ON d2.product > d1.product),
cte2 AS
(SELECT 
customer, p1 || p2 AS p
FROM data d
INNER JOIN cte ON d.product = cte.p1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE customer = d.customer AND product = cte.p2))
SELECT p, COUNT(*)
FROM cte2 GROUP BY p;
```

Please note that this yields:

| Product | Count |
| --- | --- |
| AB | 2 |
| AC | 2 |
| BC | 2 |

which is different from your expected output (you have AC 1).  However since both customer3 and customer4 have A and C in your data, I take my result to be correct.  Otherwise please explain why you only want AC 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A_B AS (select 
Products, 
count(distinct customers) as total_distinct_customers
From Table 
group by Products
where Products = 'A' and 'B'),

WITH B_C AS (select 
Products, 
count(distinct customers) as total_distinct_customers
From Table 
group by Products
where Products = 'B' and 'C'),

WITH C_D AS (select 
Products, 
count(distinct customers) as total_distinct_customers
From Table 
group by Products
where Products = 'C' and 'D')

SELECT * FROM A_B
UNION ALL B_C
UNION ALL C_D
```

Comment: Thank you! this works, but its for a small set of data. i have about 500 products hence difficult to scale

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a *self join* and `group by`:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, count(*)
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.product < t2.product and t1.customer = t2.customer
group by t1.product, t2.product;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d4a1946fc51888f6ccf5c26876991cf